# Get remaining horizontal space in algorithmicx

Tags: indentation, algorithmicx

How can I get the correct remaining width for a block in algorithmicx? I tried to use the `\linewidth`, but it seems to not include the indentation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}

\makeatletter
\newlength\FunName@Indent

\algblockdefx[FunctionLike]{FunctionLike}{EndFunctionLike}[4]{%
    \def\Fun@Start{\textbf{#1} \textsc{#2}[}%
    \settowidth\FunName@Indent{\Fun@Start}%
    \Fun@Start\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\FunName@Indent}{#3](#4)}
}{}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
    \FunctionLike{Fun}{MyFunction}{arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10}{foo}
        \FunctionLike{Rule}{Foo}{arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10}{foo}

        \EndFunctionLike
    \EndFunctionLike
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the Rule Foo has a line break due to the incorrect width of the parbox.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `\ALG@tlm` stores the indentation length. So it also has to be subtracted:

```
\dimexpr\linewidth-\FunName@Indent-\ALG@tlm
```

Result:

[image: output]

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}

\makeatletter
\newlength\FunName@Indent

\algblockdefx[FunctionLike]{FunctionLike}{EndFunctionLike}[4]{%
    \def\Fun@Start{\textbf{#1} \textsc{#2}[}%
    \settowidth\FunName@Indent{\Fun@Start}%
    \Fun@Start\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\FunName@Indent-\ALG@tlm}{#3](#4)}
}{}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
    \FunctionLike{Fun}{MyFunction}{arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10}{foo}
        \FunctionLike{Rule}{Foo}{arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10}{foo}
            \FunctionLike{Rule}{Foo}{arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10}{foo}
                \FunctionLike{Rule}{Foo}{arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10}{foo}
                    \FunctionLike{Rule}{Foo}{arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10}{foo}
                    \EndFunctionLike
                \EndFunctionLike
            \EndFunctionLike
        \EndFunctionLike
    \EndFunctionLike
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the notation for `\ALG@tlm` refers to `t`his `l`eft `m`argin, which changes as you're indenting through structures.

Comment: @Werner this sounds like a good explaination for the name. So this is the correct size to use?

Comment: From the looks of it, yes. [`algpseudocode`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty) defines `\textproc` as the formatting command for functions/procedures (which uses `\textsc`). If you're using `algpseudocode`, you could use that to be a bit more `algorithmicx`-y.

Comment: @someonr I believe you meant `\ALG@tlm` instead of `\FunName@Indent` in the solution description right ?

Comment: @BambOo thanks, I fixed it.